# Не работает mytop

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, ubuntu

запустил mytop

```
 mytop --prompt -d db
```

Запросы не выводятся. Я думаю, потому что они уже выполнились.
Как мне посмотреть все запросы к базе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mytop` работает как классический `top` - показывает срез текущего состояния. Если ваши запросы уже отработали и баз данных простаивает, то запросов вы не увидите, они, как правило, отрабатывают очень быстро. Если вы хотите видеть историю ваших запросов, вам нужен лог с вашими запросами.

По умолчанию логгирование в MySQL отключено, так как это довольно затратная операция. Однако, можно включить логгирование запросов, для этого в конфигурационном файле my.cnf, в секции [myqld] следует

```
general_log=1
general_log_file=/path/to/log
```

Вместо /path/to/log следует подставить путь к лог-файлу. Логгирование включается после перезагрузки сервера. Чтобы следить за логом в реальном времени, можно воспользоваться командой `tail`, передав ей параметр `-f` и при необходимости количество выводимых последних строк

```
tail -200f /path/to/log
```